# how to load a csv file into java that contains multiple whitespaces

Tags: java, csv, text-files

Wondering how to load a csv file into java and print out the results. So far I can't get it to print out the whole csv sheet. The sheet contains white spaces and looks like this with a header:

```
Sales num, Account num, Date, Delivery, Codes
Sales 1,    2345   ,     May17,  Oct318, 3345                                                                        
                                         4435
                                         2234
Sales 2,   3345,         May 18, Oct318, 4456
```

There are multiple codes per a sale, but all the other info (account num, data, delivery) only has one. After the codes the second sales is put in, so there is alot of white space between sales 1 and sale 2.

I have this code that I found, but it only prints the first two words.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{


  try {
   ArrayList < String > ar = new ArrayList < String > ();
   File csvFile = new File("C:\\Users\\AZ0000\\Documents\\Book1.csv\\");
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
   String line = "";
   StringTokenizer st = null;
   int lineNumber = 0;
   int tokenNumber = 0;

   while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

    String[] arr = line.split(",");

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     //System.out.println(arr[0]+" " + arr[1] + arr); // h

    }

    lineNumber++;
    //use comma as token separator 

   }
  } catch (IOException ex) {

   ex.printStackTrace();

  }
```

I will eventually need to take out the data from the csv and import it to certain lines in a text file.

Comment: It only prints the first two words, because you only print the first two words: `arr[0]+" " + arr[1]`. The whitespace is not the problem.

Comment: So how do I print out the whole thing

Comment: `System.out.print(arr[i]+" ")` inside, and a `System.out.println()` directly after the for loop.

Comment: There is a lot of white space after the Codes. Is there any way to get ride of all the space and to line it up so it is under the correct header?

Comment: I used line.split ( "   "); which helped the white space issue. but is there a way to line them all up better and under the headers

Comment: Something like this for padding: `String.format("%-10s",arr[i])`

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure why the spaces are becoming a problem, but take a look at [jSefa](http://jsefa.sourceforge.net/index.html).

It allows you to serialize objects to CSV.

```
@CsvDataType()
public class Person {

   @CsvField(pos = 1)
   String name;

   @CsvField(pos = 2, format = "dd.MM.yyyy")
   Date birthDate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just use proper parser as it's more reliable.

[univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) removes any unwanted whitespaces by default, is WAY faster than using `line.split(",");`, and will handle things such as quotes, line endings and delimiters in your fields.

Try this code:

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
settings.detectFormatAutomatically();

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new File("C:\\Users\\AZ0000\\Documents\\Book1.csv"));
```

Hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache 2.0 license)

Answer (score 0):

If the format looks like you pase, then its simply not a csv ...
proper format should be like

```
Sales num, Account num, Date, Delivery, Codes
Sales 1,    2345   ,     May17,  Oct318, 3345                                                                        
Sales 1,    2345   ,     May17,  Oct318, 4435
Sales 1,    2345   ,     May17,  Oct318, 2234
Sales 2,   3345,         May 18, Oct318, 4456
```

Or use another separator to split multiple values in one column, eg.

```
Sales num, Account num, Date, Delivery, Codes
Sales 1,    2345   ,     May17,  Oct318, 3345;4435;2234
Sales 2,   3345,         May 18, Oct318, 4456
```

From my point of view, the best approach is to have file like

```
Sales num,Account num,Date,Delivery,Codes
Sales 1,2345,May 17,Oct318,3345;4435;2234
Sales 2,3345,May 18,Oct318,4456
```

Then simply read row, split by comma `,` , last column split by `;`